# nodejs alpha v2.0.0: How to track fallback count?

Tags: actions-on-google

Currently I'm able to set the fallback count within an intent using the following:

```
conv.fallbackCount = 0;
```

I'm able to retrieve this value and iterate it from a called function:

```
conv.fallbackCount = parseInt(conv.fallbackCount, 10);
conv.fallbackCount++;
```

The issue I'm having is that when using a generic catch-all fallback intent, because I'm using the same 'conv => {}' when defining the fallback intent, the previous intent's fallbackCount is lost/NaN.

```
app.intent('input.unknown', conv => {
  conv.fallbackCount = parseInt(conv.fallbackCount, 10);
})
```

How do you think I can solve this?

I was thinking that I could store the previous intent's conv or fallback count in its context parameters then parse this in the generic fallback intent, however I'm unsure if I could iterate the fallback count stored in the conv fallback field.

Any tips?

Thanks :)

---

Update:

```
conv.user.storage.fallbackCount = 1;
```

Comment: You could store in `app.data` as long as you know to clear the data after a vaid intent is run: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data

Comment: Thanks for the linked page, it helped me out. In the alpha v2 nodejs library the 'app.data' line doesn't work.


What worked for me was:

  "conv.user.storage.fallbackCount = 1;"  

Their documentation says that user storage needs permission in some countries for personal information, but a fallback count wouldn't count, right?

Regarding clearing the data, I set it to 0 in every successful intent, do you mean entirely removing the variable from data after every successful intent instead of zero'ing it out?

Comment: Ah, I see:   app.userStorage = {}; , I'll use conv.user.storage = {};